# how many dp increase for 8 px in android

Tags: android

This is my xml. I have to convert px to dp my try again Textview when I gave 40dp , 40 dp padding left and right side then my expected designed is greater  8 px from my current designed.

how much padding I have to increase in try_again textview so that my current and expected design should same?

I am setting padding in dp not in px.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tesco_blue"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_18"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/margin_12"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_18">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/securebarcode_error_layout_variant_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_56"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_56"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errortitle"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.White"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
            tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errordesc"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
            tools:text="@string/pwp_network_error_description" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pwp_progressbarlayout_variant_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"


            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_48"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/try_again"
            style="@style/Typeface.Body.Bold.HighlightBlue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/error_button_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/cl_40"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/cl_40"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_12"
            android:text="@string/Tryagain"
            android:textColor="@color/fdv_pending_state_color" />


        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: each 1dp ==1.5 px that's mean 5.4

Comment: then how much we have to increase for left and right padding

Comment: your expected designed is greater 8 px from your current designed,  and you gave it 40 dp so your design should be 46~dp

Comment: means 43 left and 43 right  padding is it?

Comment: Right , try it and let me know,

Comment: @SariMasri ok i will check and let you know i send it for design review  will updated you